# evitar multiples sesiones del mismo usuario en navegadores diferentes

Tags: php

tengo una duda que puede que me ayuden a resolver por favor.

tengo este código php llamado login.php el cual es el inicio de sesión al sistema, pero quiero evitar que el usuario que tenga una sesión activa, pueda iniciar sesión en otro navegador o computadora.

```html
 <?php
  //iniciando sesion
  
  include_once 'conexion.php';
  $user = $_POST['usuario'];
  $pass = $_POST['clave'];
  //buscar en la BD los datos suministrados de usuario y clave
  $bypass = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '{$user}' AND clave='{$pass}'");
  //almacena en una variable si encuentra algun resultado de la consulta
  $count = $bypass->num_rows;
  //variable que contiene los datos del usuario
  $act = $bypass->fetch_object();
  if ($count == 1) {
    //almacenando variables como objetos
    if ($act->IDstatus == 1) {
      //Iniciando la sesion
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['On'] = $user;
      $_SESSION['Pf'] = $act->tipo;
      $_SESSION['Us'] = $act->usuario;
      //guarda acción realizada en la tabla historial para control de sesion de usuario
      $action="El Usuario {$user} a iniciado sesion";
      $bita=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO historial (accion,fecha,hora) VALUES('{$action}',CURDATE(),CURTIME()) ");
      // abre la pagina inicio.php
      header('location: index.php');
      } elseif ($act->IDstatus == 2) { ?>
        <script>
        swal.fire({
          title: 'ATENCION!',
          html: 'El Usuario NO SE ENCUENTRA ACTIVO, contacte al Administrador',
          icon: 'error',
          confirmButtonText: 'Verificar'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            window.location = 'vista-acceso.php';
          }
        });
      </script>
    <?php
      mysqli_close($mysqli); //cerramos la conexion
    }
  } else {?>
    <script>
      swal.fire({
        title: 'ATENCION!',
        html: 'El Usuario y/o Clave son incorrectos',
        icon: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'Verificar'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          window.location = 'vista-acceso.php';
        }
      });
    </script>
  <?php
    mysqli_close($mysqli); //cerramos la conexion
  } ?>
</body>

vi que guardando la sesión en la base de datos al intentar iniciar sesión con una consulta lo comprobara, pero soy realmente nuevo y me daba muchos errores.

Espero puedan ayudarme.
```

Comment: Utiliza un token (jwt o cualquier otro). Lo guardas en la tabla del usuario y cada petición que haga SIEMPRE compruebas el token, si no es igual al que tienes en la tabla, lo deslogueas. Cada vez que haga un login, actualizas el token en la tabla y se lo devuelves para que te lo reenvíe siempre. En el momento en que haga un segundo login, automáticamente estarás invalidando el primero. En vez de un token puedes usar el número de sesión, pero no me gusta usar datos privados para estas cosas. Creo que es la manera más sencilla de hacer lo que buscas